# How to create a stacked bar chart grouped by 2 category

Tags: charts, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a data table, group in 2 category A and B as below

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPIWh.png)

How can I create a stacked bar chart like that

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mam1Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a single built in way to make a chart with bars or columns that are able to split like that.

I think the closest you could do would be to make to bar charts back to back. One would filter for Cat A and the other for Cat B.

The legend for each table could be used or a separate legend could be made from a rectangle and some text boxes. The bars' colors would need to be set otherwise it would Automatically use the same initial color for both.

[image]

To make the left chart go in the reverse direction, click on the bottom x-Axis and set the Reverse property to True.

Then Hide the Y-Axis of the Chart B.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggest, is there really no other way :(